# Maximum number of intersecting subsets with size at most k

Tags: co.combinatorics

My question is assume that we have a set with $n\geq 2k$ elements and we want to find the maximal number of pairwise intersecting subsets of $[n]$ with at most $k$ elements?

Comment: Look up Erdös–Ko–Rado theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem

Comment: By Erdös–Ko–Rado the number of subsets of size $r\leqslant k$ is at most ${n-1\choose r-1}$, so totally maximum $\sum_{r=1}^k {n-1\choose k-1}$. A collection of all subsets containing the same element shows that this bound is sharp.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks for your answer. But I think this will show the lower bound. I'm looking for the maximum number of subsets.

Comment: It is both upper and lower bound

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks I think you are right